# If() Logic not working after xamarin update

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, logic, xamarin.android

Iam working with xamarin and monotouch and monodroid.

I have a strange problem - I just updated to the newest update in visual studio 2013 and monodroid.

In of of my classes I have the following code:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Password) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Username))
            {
                return;
            }
```

Password and Username are property strings and no matter what it always
evaluate true. If both have values it still says true. Its very frustrating as
none of my code is working after the update.

Does anybody have a suggestion what to do

EDIT:
After some more digging I believe the debugger was playing a trick on me. It seemed that it hit the return when stepping - but actually it executed the subsequent code correct. However I needed to change the code. It was some simple date calculation.

```
var seventies = new DateTime (1970, 1, 1);
            var time = DateTime.UtcNow - seventies.ToUniversalTime ();
```

However this triggered an out of range exception which stopped my appflow. I changed it to

```
var epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
            var d = DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract (epoch);
```

And now it seems to work. I don't like the fact that the debugger led me to believe something else was wrong. I don't like either that the datetime calculation which worked for the past year suddenly stops working.

Comment: You have this in both iOS and Android ? That would be a compiler regression in mono itself. Could you file a bug report and state which version of the compiler you're using ? (could be 3.8 or 3.10, depending on which channel you are subscribed, or something else if mono was not updated).

Comment: I just edited my question - I have the problem in monodroid and visual studio 2013. The same code work as it should in ios and xamarin studio for mac.